# what is this symbol != in node.js jade file?

Tags: node.js, pug

May I know what does the code in .jade file below means? Particularly the sign "!=" ?

> body   section.contaner!= body

Thanks

Comment: this might help for a start http://jade-lang.com/reference/ Look for Unescaped Buffered Code

Comment: The jade documentation would be best for seeking answers on jade syntax. Do check that before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

In Jade templating `!=` means that unescaped content will be displayed

Examples:

```
p= 'This code is' + ' <escaped>!'
```

Gives

```
<p>This code is &lt;escaped&gt;!</p>
```

And this example:

```
p!= 'This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!'
```

Gives

```
<p>This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!</p>
```

You can see that in the first example only `=` was used whereas second example used `!=`.

I hope that will help.